# Deploying create-react-app to Heroku and ignoring /src folder

Tags: heroku, deployment, create-react-app

I'm deploying my create-react-app to Heroku using this buildpack https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

It does an awesome job, but I see all of my folder/files from my /src directory when I checked the deployed version

[image]

When I check the `index.html`. I see that it's using the production build, so I know it's working and not using any of the /src files.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/main.0156c40e.js">
    <link href="./static/css/main.29266132.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

How do I filter out my development files when deploying?